# What is this date format called and how do I parse it?

Tags: php, parsing, date

I have a weird date format in some files I'm parsing. Here are some examples:

```
1954203
2012320
2010270
```

The first four digits are the year and the next three digits are day of year. For example, the first date is the 203rd day of 1954, or 7/22/1954.

My questions are:

1. What's this date format called?
2. Is there a pre-canned way to parse it? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention my language. PHP.

Comment: This format is usually called an [ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates). It is sometimes also (incorrectly) called a [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_Date).

Comment: This data format isn't that weird.  It's easier to sort dates based on the year and day of year rather then dealing with months (even if they're stored as numbers) and day of month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Yz', 201026);
echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Doesn't work because `date_parse_from_format()` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @R.Bemrose yes, true. But that doesn't seem to be the OP's problem, he claims that it returns a broken result

Comment: The answer has been changed since I originally commented on it. This works just fine. However, you have to subtract 1 from the day in order for the result to be accurate (try a date of 2010001 to see what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

For Java, see [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You want yyyyDDD as the format (year, then day in year).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get it as a string in C#...

```
DateTime GetDate(string input)
{
    int year = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(0,4));
    int day = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(4,3));
    return (new DateTime(year,1,1)).AddDays(day - 1);
}
```

(Note the -1 offset for the day number, since you are already starting at day 1)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP to format the date:

```
echo date_parse_from_format("Yz", $date);
```

You can also use

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("YZ", $date);
```

or it's alias

```
date_create_from_format("Yz", $date)
```

which returns a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

Comment: You would think that would work but it doesn't. It returns January 204th, 1954 and tells me the date is invalid.

Comment: @Jason but that is expected behaviour: You are dumping the `DateTime` object. You need to format the date to get it in the form you desire. Try `echo date_format(date_parse_from_format("Yz", '1954203'), "d-m-Y");`

Comment: That gives an error. I don't care to go any further down this path, though, since one of the other answers has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I wanted was this:

```
$date = '1954203';
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
$day = substr($date, 4, 3);
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(1, 1, 1, 1, $day, $year));
```

Comment: Awww, I'm not sure whether this is not a good idea, as it will have to work with negative timestamps. (Unix time starts January 1st, 1970). If you can, use one of the `DateTime` suggestions

Comment: Good point. I wish I had a better solution. However, this works for dates on or after January 1st, 1902, which suits my purpose well enough.